# Sorting foreach by date give Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Tags: php, sorting, joomla, foreach, usort

I have a .php that retrieve fields from my Joomla database and then echo them with a foreach function:

```
<?php                   
  $jquery1 = "SELECT `fulltext`,alias,metakey,publish_up,metadesc FROM xxx_content  WHERE catid=22 AND state= '1'";
  $jdb1->setQuery( $jquery1 );
  $jfeed1= $jdb1->loadObjectList();
  foreach ($jfeed1 as $jitem1):
?>
<li>
 <div>
  <?php                                 
  $oldLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_US');
  echo strftime("%a %d %b %Y", strtotime($jitem1->publish_up)); 
  setlocale(LC_TIME, $oldLocale);
  ?>
 </div>
 <div><?php echo $jitem1->fulltext; ?></div>
</li> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

However I would like to sort the foreach function by date, I have tried two different way of doing it (based on other SE questions) but each time I get this warning:

```
Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in...
```

Here is my first try:

```
$jfeed1= $jdb1->loadObjectList();
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
   $t1 = strtotime($a['publish_up']);
   $t2 = strtotime($a['publish_up']);
   return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($jitem1, 'date_compare');
foreach ($jfeed1 as $jitem1):
```

And here was my second try:

```
$jfeed1= $jdb1->loadObjectList();
usort($jfeed1->publish_up, function($a, $b) {
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $b);
return $date1 > $date2;
});
foreach ($jfeed1 as $jitem1):
```

I've "learned" php just by looking at codes and tuto, so I am missing a lot of fondamental notions that why I don't understand what I am supposed to do to solve this warning. Thanks for your help!

EDIT 1:
The function

```
<?php
    var_dump($jfeed1)
?>
```

gives me for the first item:

```
array(22) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#318 (5) { ["fulltext"]=> string(212) "Yesterday ..." ["alias"]=> string(3) "237" ["metakey"]=> string(7) "Romania" ["publish_up"]=> string(19) "2011-11-15 09:06:39" }
```

EDIT 2

```
$jfeed1= $jdb1->loadObjectList();

function date_compare($a, $b)
{
   $t1 = strtotime($a['publish_up']);
   $t2 = strtotime($b['publish_up']);
   return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($jfeed1, 'date_compare');
foreach ($jfeed1 as $jitem1):
```

Comment: The input in this function is not an array, but NULL (=nothing). Your variable has no value. Maybe a typo, of the function/method doesnt return anything.

Comment: What is the content of `$jfeed1` after your `loadObjectList()` call ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet. Well I don't know. I have search for $jfeed1 in my .php and all of them are in the code above. I have uploaded my full .php here http://www.docspal.com/viewer?id=twgcbiyc-6316723. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: `var_dump($jfeed1)` - *look* at your values to figure out what they are.

Comment: @deceze, I have added the result of var_dump($jfeed1) at the bottom of my question. The value that I want to use is publish_up (the last one)

Comment: @deceze so it seems that publish_up isn't Null or empty, any idea what is wrong here? (here is the full var_dump($jfeed1) http://20000km.com/fr/?option=com_content&view=article&id=302&catid=2&Itemid=101

Comment: `$jfeed1` is an array, not an object. So `$jfeed1->publish_up` can't exist. What do you want to do? Sort by the `publish_up` value of each array entry? Then you need to use that value inside the comparison function, not as the first argument to `usort`.

Comment: Thanks @deceze! Yes that's what I want to do. I don't really get what you mean by "Then you need to use that value inside the comparison function, not as the first argument to usort". I have tried the code (see the one at the very end of my question, below EDIT 2) but it isn't working. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort out each array entry by the date directly in the query with:

```
ORDER BY publish_up DESC (descending order)
ORDER BY publish_up ASC (ascending order)
```

As in:

```
$jquery1 = "SELECT `fulltext`,alias,metakey,publish_up,metadesc FROM xxx_content  WHERE catid=22 AND state= '1' ORDER BY publish_up ASC";
```

If you want to keep this PHP function `date_compare` then you have to replace:

```
$a['publish_up']
```

by

```
$a->publish_up
```

As in:

```
$jfeed1= $jdb1->loadObjectList();
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
   $t1 = strtotime($a->publish_up);
   $t2 = strtotime($b->publish_up);
   return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($jfeed1, 'date_compare');
foreach ($jfeed1 as $jitem1):
```

`return $t1 - $t2;` is ascending

`return $t2 - $t1;` is descending